# How do I add an OCaml library reference to a Reason code file?

Tags: ocaml, reason

Just began with Reason and OCaml today. I've started with the https://github.com/esy-ocaml/hello-reason sample. I want to make a HTTP API call so I've installed [ocaml-cohttp](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp#client-tutorial) with: `esy add @opam/cohttp-lwt`.

Now I want to use that library (or any that you may have as a suggestion) within the hello-reason getting started sample.

I can't find reference documentation on how to import it. I've tried:

`open cohttp-lwt`

Can I use OCaml libraries within in Reason code files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only difference is syntax. The [client tutorial](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp#client-tutorial) can be [translated directly, and automatically](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&ocaml=PYBwpgdgBAMg7gFwFCklAwsAFghIXjSY54D6ANoqQK4QCWAHkkuWAlAEbAAmAnlAF4kUDOTqQEAOgDmbKAAoAqgCc6k4ADNSAZwSqI0qACISIbQC4A9Jbi3JysN250pAY2ABbS0YCUUAHz+AlAatAoO2iAANJw8vH4AtP7CUKzs7txgglARIFAAPv5QAEpgkcAQ2mCSugCGCNTaBUWYmZIZYKSaOgj1jVB0ECkACvoIGpIgYxrGpeWVWR3mUACk3AA6EEZQHQDcI9OT08YAEmC1mcoWq9qb2-K5zSVlIBVVkljnl02FUGcXYGUkgQwB6+mkPn2Ii4fCexFwIAoiEkACE4sDQbpwQF8sFQtAYfwkgdBuMjqSZkY0bDNKlINIEFhlms7goAMp6QbSSSsAyM2J8SEpQnMNIKPxCERiwnZeAIUgeWqDexhGWDFJTUmkSDcMQQLLyIylVxgOgAN0cAt4rIAelafEA) into this:

```ml
open Lwt;
open Cohttp;
open Cohttp_lwt_unix;

let body =
  Client.get(Uri.of_string("https://www.reddit.com/"))
  >>= (
    ((resp, body)) => {
      let code = resp |> Response.status |> Code.code_of_status;
      Printf.printf("Response code: %d\n", code);
      Printf.printf(
        "Headers: %s\n",
        resp |> Response.headers |> Header.to_string,
      );
      body
      |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string
      >|= (
        body => {
          Printf.printf("Body of length: %d\n", String.length(body));
          body;
        }
      );
    }
  );

let () = {
  let body = Lwt_main.run(body);
  print_endline("Received body\n" ++ body);
};
```

*Edit: `hello-reason` uses [ocaml-dune](/questions/tagged/ocaml-dune), so you also have to add `cohttp-lwt-unix` to the `libraries` stanza in the project's `dune` file, as [shown in the client tutorial here](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp#compile-and-execute-with-dune).*

Comment: I also had to add `esy add @opam/lwt_ssl`